# Showing Parent with Many Children list in JSP

Tags: java, json, web-services, jsp, spring-mvc

I have to call Rest API from Spring MVC/Spring Maven project which has response JSON as following:

```
Content-Type: application/wrml
{
    parent-repository: {parent-repositoryId}
    type: {repository-type}
    object-types: {object-typeId-list}
    children
    {
         {repositoryId1} 
         {
             type: {repository-type1}
             object-types: {object-typeId-list}
             children
             {
              …
             }
         }
…
         {repositoryIdN} 
         {
             type: {repository-typeN}
             object-types: {object-typeId-list}
             children
             {
              …
             }
         }

    }  
}
```

The response is a searched for repository. How can I display Parent and it's Children response in the JSP? Do I need to list them for displaying?

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Also you would need to unmarshall the JSON into either a bean or some form of nested `Map<String, Object>` before it is then passed to the JSP. Are you calling the JSON service from Java/Spring on the server or via AJAX in Javascript on the client?

Comment: The JSON shown above is just example. Well, I am using JSONObject class to set all data in it.

Comment: "The JSON shown above" is not JSON - it looks like the `toString()` output of your `JSONObject`. So it appears you want to use the JSONObject in your JSP page (not what your question is actually asking)? This is possible but not the best way to go. IMHO you are better off un-marshalling the JSON into a simple DTO bean (instead of a JSONObject) and then calling the `getFoo()` methods of that bean in your JSP page.

Comment: Well I want to convert the JSON response from REST API/WCF Service into List/ArrayList so that, I can pass it into JSP. The main question is how I can show them in JSP, as 1 parent have multiple childrens, and also sub-children may have childrens as well. How can convert the response into a manner that it can be properly displayed in JSP.

Comment: Yes this is hard in pure JSP as it would require a lot of ugly `if` and `forEach` statements. The usual way to do this is to create a DTO class (bean) that mimics the structure of your JSON format. In the case of the children, you would have a field called "children" that was a `List` of `child` beans (defined as a separate or inner class), etc. Then in the JSP you would iterate over the children with a forEach tag: `<c:forEach items="${entity.children}" var="child">type: ${child.type}</c:forEach>`